# Is the field of complex numbers complete?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, real-numbers, complete-spaces

I know that the complex numbers can't be ordered, does this imply that the field $\mathbb{F}$ of $\mathbb{C}$ is not complete? do we need any other proof other than what I stated? Can we use the same logic for quaternions?

Comment: Topologically, they are both complete metric spaces in the usual metric.

Comment: What do you mean the field that consists of $\Bbb{R}$ and $\Bbb{C}$? Also, generally the property of having a total order is independent of completeness.

Comment: @SortofDamocles My bad, I've edited it.

Comment: As @ncmathsadist noted, $\Bbb{C}$ is a complete metric space, which means every cauchy sequence converges to a limit in the space. Actually you don't need the algebraic structure at all to talk about completeness -- hence my question. $\Bbb{C}$ is complete as a metric space; it just also happens to have a field structure.

Comment: I want to piggyback off of this question: is the notion of completeness a tautology? the definition of a complete field is that every cauchy sequence converges. Therefore, we say that every cauchy sequence in a complete field converges.

Comment: @SortofDamocles I guess it kind of make sense now. I thought that, as you've stated it, a metric space was complete when every cauchy sequence converges to a limit in the space, but i assumed that since the distance between points in the space was compared to some $\varepsilon>0$ we have an ordered set in a complex field, which was confusing.

Comment: @kvd I understand your point of view completely! The trick is to notice that it's OK to have several points at the same distance from the limit point -- in the case of $\Bbb{C}$, they are arranged in a circle around the limit point.

Comment: @SortofDamocles That clears the confusion, thank you!

Comment: @user29418: No. Consider the field of rational numbers $\Bbb Q.$ There are all kinds of Cauchy sequences that don't converge in $\Bbb Q,$ so $\Bbb Q$ is a field that is not complete. You seem to have noticed, rather, that being complete is equivalent to fitting the definition of being complete...but that's how definitions always work.

Comment: thank you @CameronBuie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of the real numbers, every bounded sequence admits a convergent subsequence. Since every Cauchy sequence is bounded, it admits a convergent subsequence, whence we conclude that it converges (why?). Consequently, the set of real numbers is complete. Based on the completeness of the reals, you can prove the completeness of the complex numbers as follows.

Suppose that $z_{n} = (x_{n},y_{n})\in\mathbb{C}$ is a Cauchy sequence of complex numbers. This means that:
\begin{align*}
(\forall\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0})(\exists n_{\varepsilon}\in\mathbb{N})(\forall m,n\in\mathbb{N})(m\geq n \geq n_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |z_{m} - z_{n}| < \varepsilon)
\end{align*}

Given that $|z_{m} - z_{n}| \geq |x_{m} - x_{n}|$ and $|z_{m} - z_{n}| \geq |y_{m} - y_{n}|$, we conclude that $x_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ and $y_{n}\in\mathbb{R}$ are Cauchy sequences of real numbers. Consequently, they converge to $x$ and $y$, let's say. If we denote by $z = (x,y)$, it results that $z_{n}$ converges to $z$ (why?), whence we conclude that $\mathbb{C}$ is complete.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

A simple Google search yielded this:"In mathematics, a complete field is a field equipped with a metric and complete with respect to that metric. Basic examples include the real numbers, the complex numbers, and complete valued fields (such as the p-adic numbers)." If this is what you mean by "complete", then yes the field of complex numbers is complete. Being equipped with a metric and being complete with respect to that metric means the field is equipped with a distance function and that the field is complete with respect to that distance function. I hope this answers your question.